# 'Protoc' command in a parent directory outputs entire source directory in the python_out directory

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-python

I have a directory named `protos` which holds a single `.proto` file, but will eventually hold many. This directory has a sibling named `app` , where I would like to dump the built `grpc` python files.

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that will invoke the `protoc` command and build `.proto` files in `protos`, and output the built files to `app`

Below is a `tree` of where I've placed each file.

```
├── build_protos.sh
└── trainingInstance (root module directory)
    |
    ├── app
    │   ├── app.py
    |   ├── (where I'd like my built files to go)
    |   |
    |   └──trainingInstance
    |      └──protos
    |         └──(where the built files actually go)
    |
    └── protos
        └── TrainingService.proto (what I'd like to compile)
```

When I run `build_protos.sh`, the file `TrainingService.proto` is detected fine and built, but instead of placing the built file into `...trainingInstance/app/<file>` , it instead places it in `...trainingInstance/app/trainingInstance/protos/<file>` (see above).

I thought I had solved this problem by explicitly setting the `proto_path` to `protos`, but it doesn't seem to care either way. Below is my `build_protos.sh` file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

working_dir=$(pwd)
proto_dirs=($(pwd)/trainingInstance)

for dir in $proto_dirs
do
    srcdir=$dir/protos #./trainingInstance/protos
    destdir=$dir/app #./trainingInstance/app
    echo Building $dir protos...

    python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc\
        -I $working_dir\
        --proto_path=$srcdir\
        --python_out=$destdir\
        --grpc_python_out=$destdir\
        $srcdir/*.proto #./trainingInstance/protos/*.proto

done
```

So does anyone know how to stop protoc from making these reflected directories in the output directory? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not 5 minutes after posting this question (after previously playing with the script for an hour), I've solved my own problem: the `-I` flag, which is pointed to my working-directory, forces `protoc` to build files in this manner, since it aims to keep different `.proto` packages separate. This issue is fixed by removing the `-I` flag entirely.

I feel I should leave this here in-case anyone else has a similar issue.

Comment: indeed, you should definitely leave this here for others to benefit from this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with `pip install grpcio-tools-1.51.1` as of 2022-01-13. The message is: `File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).`